# Unusual string collision in PHP

Tags: php

I have an array of lower case hex strings. For some reason, in_array is finding matches where none exist:

```
$x = '000e286592';
$y = '0e06452425';
$testarray = [];
$testarray[] = $x;
if (in_array($y, $testarray)) {
    echo "Array element ".$y." already exists in text array ";
}
print_r($testarray);exit();
```

The in_array comes back as true, as if '0e06452425' is already in the array. Which it is not. Why does this happen and how do I stop it from happening?

Comment: `print($x + $y)` resolves as `0`. Likely because of the same reason: loose comparisons, implicit casting., and type juggling. It's interpreting the string `0e06452425` as "0  times 10 raised to 6452425" which is `0`. So `0` is in fact in the array that also contains `0` and you get a `true`. It's silly, but php is often silly.

Comment: Issue happens only if the string starts with "0". Looks like some bug and the in_array may be treating the string as octal integer

Answer (score 2):

Odd. This has something to do with the way that PHP compares the values in "non-strict" mode; passing the third argument (`strict`) as `true` no longer results in a false positive:

```
if (in_array($y, $testarray, true)) {
    echo "Array element ".$y." already exists in text array ";
}
```

I'm still trying to figure out why, technically speaking, this doesn't work without strict checking enabled.

Comment: PHP defaults to truthy statements and loose comparisons by default .. Setting to `true` forces strict comparison.

Comment: If a number begins with 0 it will be handled as octal not decimal. That's why you need strict comparision to take it as strings. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

Comment: @MarkusZeller not with string casting, only with numeric literals. `(int)'012'` is `12`, `012` is `10`.

Comment: @Sammitch When you do a typeless comparision PHP internally tries a cast match before comparing. So you're correct, it is not a casting problem. So I think JNevill`s comment on the question takes part here.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a boolean as third parameter to [in_array()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to enable PHP strict comparison instead of the default [loose comparison](https://www.copterlabs.com/strict-vs-loose-comparisons-in-php/).

Try this code

```php
$x = '000e286592';
$y = '0e06452425';
$testarray = [];
$testarray[] = $x;
if (in_array($y, $testarray, true)) {
    echo "Array element ".$y." already exists in text array ";
}
print_r($testarray);exit();
```